# Multi-threaded wait/syncing code only works correctly, if printing to console

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, rendering

Here is a commented piece of the code that I am talking about. This code may seem a bit pointless, but it was way more complicated and I kept simplifying it to find this problem:

```
void tRender(Renderer* renderer, Window* win) {
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    while(true) {
        renderer->isBusy = true;
        renderer->draw(win); /* draws screen with a square at x position reading a var from logic */
        renderer->isBusy = false; /* same issue applies if done inside renderer->draw */
        Sleep(500); // completely arbitrary, but shows the lack of sync
    }
}

void tLogic(Logic* logic, Renderer* renderer) {
    unsigned long loops = 0;

    while (true) {
        ++loops;

        if (true) {
            ++(logic->positions[0][0]);
            printf("abc"); /* whether or not this printf exists
                              determines if it's synced */
        }

        while (renderer->isBusy) {} /* have attempted both to make it a volatile bool and
                                       a std::atomic<bool>, same results either way. */
    }
}

int main() {
    Window* win = new Window();

    Logic* logic = new Logic();
    Renderer* renderer = new Renderer(logic); /* i didn't want to use globals, so... */

    bool running = true;

    while (running) {
        std::thread threadLogic(tLogic, logic, renderer);
        tRender(renderer, win); /* GLFW rendering did not work in a thread */

        threadLogic.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The actual problem is that, without the `printf` or without a `std::cout` (either one), the moves *comically* fast across the screen and is definitely not synced with each actual render. With the printf, however, it is for the most part, synced perfectly. The dis-assembly (according to Visual Studio) is not changed at all between each version besides the printf itself. I have checked and all compiler optimization options are completely turned off. What could the problem possibly be?

Comment: While `tRender` sleeps, `tlogic` would run its loop many times and increment `logic->positions[0][0]` by a large number. It's not at all clear what you expect to be synchronized with what else.

Comment: But wouldn't my `while (render->isBusy)` cause it to wait for isBusy to become false?

Comment: `isBusy` is false, most of the time.

Comment: I expected the position to increment only once per render, that's what I mean by synchronization.

Comment: Why did you expect that? There's nothing preventing the loop from running multiple times while `isBusy` is false.

Comment: I'm assuming that `new Window` initializes GLFW and `new Renderer` creates your OpenGL resources...you'll have better luck if you initialize GLFW and create your OpenGL resources on your rendering thread instead of newing them up on your main thread.  Without knowing more about what's going on here I can't really post an answer, but at the very least I suggest protecting all access (get and set) to `isBusy` with a `std::mutex`.

Comment: Also...
`while (renderer->isBusy) { std::this_thread::yield(); }`
...might give you better performance since it will give cycles to other threads.

Comment: @PatrickPurcell Would that not potentially *decrease* performance over a normal while loop, for example if it's late?

Comment: If you hit that `yield()` just after `isBusy` was set to `false`, you're going to come back to the beginning of your `while` loop and drop out pretty much immediately anyway.

Tbh...the main reason I would put a call to `yield()` there would be to telegraph a little more intention to coders coming through the code later.